# GNUPLOT: How to plot several curves stored in one file with different line styles

Tags: gnuplot

I have the x,y data for a number of curves stored in one file, separated by a blank line.
I want to plot the different curves with different line styles (solid, dashed ...).
How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `every` keyword to select block of datas (separated with a single empty line, so two new line character after each other), and you can use the `linestyle` keyword to explicitely define linestyle.

```
 p "data.txt" every:::0::0 w l ls 1, "" every:::1::0 w l ls 2
```

If you have not so much datas, you can write the whole command by hand. If you have more block of datas, you may prefer to use a `for` loop:

```
 p for [i=0 : maximum_number_of_curves : every_nth_curve] "data.txt" every:::i::i w l ls i
```

Please note that some terminal types does not support dashed or dotted linestyles. Use 1 as the value of every_nth_curve if you would like to use every data.
If you have double empty lines (three new line characters), you have to use the `index` keyword to select block of datas, e.g:

```
 p for [i=0 : maximum_number_of_curves : every_nth_curve] "data.txt" index i w l ls i
```

Comment: In order to determine the number of curves, use the following (requires 4.6): `stats '< sed ''s/^$/\n/'' data.txt' nooutput; maximum_number_of_curves = int(STATS_blocks)-1`. The `sed` command replaces a single empty row by two empty rows, so that each curve is considered as an own data set, which is then counted with `STATS_blocks`.

Comment: Using `sed` is a great idea but please note that it is not available on every PC however it is free for use under GNU license.

Comment: Right, but in an other question the OP said he is working on MacOSX. And, again one can use `python` or `perl` to achieve the same: `perl -pe 's/^$/\n/' data.txt`